# Gesturedetector not working in custompainter with clip

Tags: android, flutter

I am making demo for build map using svg path in flutter. But, some part is not clickable. Don't know why?
Can any one provide solution and reason for that.

Here is pathpaint code.

```
class PathPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Province _province;
  PathPainter(this._province);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Path path = getPathByProvince(_province);
    canvas.drawPath(
        path,
        Paint()
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..color = Colors.black
          ..strokeWidth = 2.0);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(PathPainter oldDelegate) => true;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(PathPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

class PathClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final Province _province;
  PathClipper(this._province);

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return getPathByProvince(_province);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Check all code

https://pastebin.com/XC7QdUtx

I am following one github project. check [here](https://github.com/gi097/flutter_clickable_regions)

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: wich region is not clickable?

Comment: @Edin Right side region not clickable.

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu I have also tried it. but not working.

Comment: Is everything you draw within the given size?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I think, drawing done outside stack.

Comment: See the project's [known issues](https://github.com/gi097/flutter_clickable_regions/blob/develop/README.md#known-issues) > Some provinces are not clickable. This is an issue of the SVG being used.

Comment: Yes I know already. But need to find solution of that.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya you find any solution?