# How to achieve Listview design on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create a listview item design something like
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBGIQ.png)

and which I have tried so far is [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq5Zm.png)

Here is my code

```
ListTile(
                leading: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 44,
                      minHeight: 44,
                      maxWidth: 64,
                      maxHeight: 64,
                    ),
                    child: Image.network(catData[index]['icon'].toString(),
                      width: 150,
                      height: 150,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      headers: headersMap,
                    )
                    ), 
                title: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10,bottom: 5, right: 10, top: 10),
                  child: Text(
                    getCategoryName(catData, index),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'Mada-Medium',
                        letterSpacing: 0.25,
                    ),
                    maxLines: 3,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10,bottom: 5, right: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      getText(catData[index]['catId'], subCatData),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: parseColor('##A2A2A2'),
                          letterSpacing: 0.25,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontFamily: 'Mada',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      maxLines: 2,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    )
                    
                    ),
              )
```

The image portion is not setting properly on listTile title. Please help to create this design

Comment: So you want the image to be positioned on the left, right?

Comment: @Unbreachable YES SIR ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/nilesh.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 120,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20),
          Expanded(
              child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
//            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text(
                'Dummy Text',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 30),
              Text(
                'Dummy Text',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
              ),
            ],
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Can you answer my question at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61135555/7783718).

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya let me try